# ReactCSSTransitionGroup not working

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm trying to make an element fade in but it doesn't do anything at all. The overall goal is to show the element when I switch the state (by clicking and trigger `showOptions()`)

I can't seem to get any of the animation working at all though, with or without this click handler.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { switchOption } from '../actions/index';

import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

class PropertyColumn extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {className: 'hidden'};
 }

 render() {
  var activeOption = null;

  this.props.options.forEach(function(option) {
   if (option.active) {
    activeOption = option;
   }
  });

  return (
   <div>
    <img src={activeOption.image_url} />
    <h2>{activeOption.name}</h2>
    <p>{activeOption.description}</p>
    <a onClick={() => this.showOptions()} href='#' className={"btn btn-primary"}>Change</a>

    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
              transitionName="example"
              className= {this.state.className}
              transitionEnterTimeout={300}
              transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
              component='ul'>
     {this.listOptions()}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
   </div>
  )
 }

 listOptions() {
  return this.props.options.map((option, i) => {
   return (
    <li onClick={() => this.props.switchOption(this.props.data, this.props.columnId, i)} key={option.id}>{option.name}</li>
   )
  })
 }

 showOptions() {
  if (this.state.className == 'visible') {
   this.setState({className: 'hidden'})
  } else {
   this.setState({className: 'visible'})
  }
 }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
  data: state.data
 }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return bindActionCreators({ switchOption }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PropertyColumn)
```

and here is the css

```html
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

Comment: We'll need more context. Can you provide a working fiddle or something similar that isolates your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2y6vqvp4/7/) with working example for you. `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` doesn't trigger animation based on css visibility properties. It triggers animation if it's child is being rendered or not.

Main changes you should make:

- `showOptions()` should toggle a boolean property of the state, **not a class name string**. No need to mess up with `className` at all.
- Base on this boolean property, make a simple ternar verification, for rendering child elements

`showOptions` could be implemented like this:

```
showOptions() {
  this.setState({isVisible: !this.state.isVisible})
}
```

And `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` component should look like:

```
<div>
    <a onClick={() => this.showOptions()} href='#' className={"btn btn-primary"}>Change</a>
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="example"
        transitionEnterTimeout={300}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
        component='div'>
            {this.state.isVisible ? ( <ul className={this.state.className}>{this.listOptions()}</ul>) : null} 
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a way to render something else as opposed to the `null`, while still triggering the animation?