# Transition not happening using ReactCSSTransitionGroup

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I've added React, React-DOM, and React Addons library to my pen.

Here's my pen:

https://codepen.io/graven_whismas/pen/QBQQmj

On clicking the button, the word in state should appear, from initial opacity of 0.4 to 1.

But as I click the button, all the content on the page disappears.

This is the error I get:

```
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=254&args[]=.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with the code in your pen that will bring about the problem you are having.

The first step is to use the development versions of the libraries, in order to get better error messages. Use `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react-with-addons.js` instead of `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react-with-addons.min.js`.

Second, loading several versions of React can cause the [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7058) your are having. Remove `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js` from the list of external scripts you are loading.

Thirdly, there is a typo when you specify the leave timeout of the animation. You have written `transtionLeaveTimeout`, where it should be `transitionLeaveTimeout`. With this type, the transition library will complain about a missing property.

This [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrJvKa) summarizes the changes you need to make.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about different versions of React. Is the library you added available on codepen? 
One other thing, I made a few changes to the new pen but the transition won't happen for some reason. Any input is very appreciated. I've just started learning Transitions using React, so my problems might seem trivial. :(

Comment: Perhaps this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361132/reactcsstransitiongroup-not-working?rq=1) will help.